# How to change image tint color of UIContextualAction of Tableview?

Tags: swift, tableview, swipe

There I want to change tint color of image but couldn't change, it's always returning white color. I have try Rendring image of Original and Template  image but still it won't work.

I have added screen shot below:

[image: I have try to change it's color but not sucessed]

please anyone can help me for that

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DocumentListCell else {return UISwipeActionsConfiguration()}
    let likeAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("likeAction ...")
        success(true)

    })

    likeAction.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Favourite_Selected")
    likeAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 239/255, green: 239/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1)

    let downloadAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Trash action ...")
    })
    downloadAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red//UIColor.init(red: 239/255, green: 239/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1)
    downloadAction.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Doc_Download_Big")

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [likeAction,downloadAction])
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Just go to `Assets.xcassets`, select the desired image.

> Replace `Render As` with the one you need:

[image]

---

## Addition

You can try also a few things:

> 2. Change the settings of the `UIImageView` itself inside your `tableView`:

```
UIImageView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableView.self]).tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 239/255, green: 239/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1)
```

> 3. Try to use extension on `UIImage`:

```
extension UIImage {
    
    func paintOver(with color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        let renderedImage = renderer.image { _ in
            color.set()
            self.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate).draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
        
        return renderedImage
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
likeAction.image = UIImage(named: "Favourite_Selected")?.colored(in: .red)
```

**Hope this one will help you!**

Comment: I have already try Rendring , as Template and as Original but it won't work

Comment: @josolution, I made additions to my answer, please check

Comment: @ kzakharc I have tried all above solutions but it won't work .

Comment: render as originalImage did the trick for me.

Comment: the extension did it

Answer (score 0):

You have to set alpha zero for background color for change image color.

Like this line:-

likeAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 239/255, green: 239/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 0)

Comment: @ Maitree-swift  I have tried this but it not work